# Any significant differences between lambda expressions & anonymous function in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

**Kotlin** has these 2 features and I think there're no significant differences between these two
regardless of :

1. syntax

```
// lambda
val toUpper = { value: String -> 
   if (value.isEmpty()) "empty value"
   else value.toUpperCase()
}

// anonymous func
val toUpper = fun(value: String): String {
  if (value.isEmpty()) return "empty value"
  else return value.toUpperCase()
}
```

2. flexibility to use *return* statement on anonymous function

I'm still digesting these features and hope you guys can help me pass through it.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems same to me, just like how `A.() -> B` is same as `(A) -> B` in bytecode (both are `KFunction1<A, B>`) but inside syntax is different `A.() -> B` lets you have `this` as receiver while `(A) -> B` lets you have variable of any name. Similarly `(String) -> String` can be assigned to both of them, i.e. fun one is also an implementation of `KFunction1<String, String>`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004914/kotlin-fun-vs-lambda-is-there-difference/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166375/kotlin-anonymous-function-use-case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kotlin fun() vs lambda is there difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58004914/kotlin-fun-vs-lambda-is-there-difference)

Comment: @KelvinM did my answer resolve your question? If so please accept the answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Two differences according to [Kotlin Reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html):

1. (I think the more significant one out of the two) An anonymous function is still a function, so returning from it behaves the same as returning from any function.  Returning from a lambda, however, actually returns from the function enclosing the lambda.
2. The return type of a lambda is inferred, while you can explicitly specify a return type for an anonymous function.

Comment: I think lambda's return type can be specified too, like val toUpper: (String) -> String { }

Comment: Kelvin M, that's not specifying the type of the lambda; it's specifying the type of variable you're assigning it to.  In your example the effect is the same — but it's not if the lambda is used as a function parameter or in a more complex expression.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the differences pointed by @jingx, you can not local return from a lambda that is not inlined.

So, the next snippet will not compile unless you add **inline** to the extension() function, thus, instructing the compiler to copy the function's content whenever it is referenced:

```
fun doSomethingWithLambda(){
    10.extension{
        if(it == 10)
            return//compiler error
    }
    println("hello")
}

fun Int.extension(f: (Int)->Unit){
    f(this)
}
```